# SBJson and swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sbjson

Does anyone know how to use SBJson library in swift?

I've this code in Objective-C

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Trying with

```
var responseString = request.responseString
let responseDict: NSDictionary = responseString.JSONValue
```

Xcode complain "() -> String does not have a member named JSONValue"

I've included

```
#import "SBJson.h"
```

in "MyProjectName"-Bridging-Header.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found: extension in SBJson apply on NSString type, but Swift String type is a different one.

It works with this code:

```
var responseString: NSString = request.responseString()
let responseDict: NSDictionary = responseString.JSONValue() as NSDictionary
```